# Magento ver. 1.9.2.4, general store information hours not showing

Tags: magento-1.9

I don't know why i can't get the configuration (general information) store hours in CMS page. I am trying to get the store hours by:

```
{{config path="general/store_information/hours"}}
```

Other information like phone, address, name and email can get easily but don't know why store hours not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer Magento CE versions, these variables seem to need to be allowed for usage in static blocks.

See **System** > **Permissions** > **Variables**

and check if `general/store_information/hours` as allowed for it to work on frontend.

Comment: Yup, that variable is not allowed there... thanks :)